# How can i redirect all page using ajax and php when a particular condition occur

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a user login part in my website using `php`, `jquery` and `ajax`.I am not much familiar with `ajax` and `jquery`.

I want to redirect my whole page to another page when the user login is correct.

But now the problem is that only the user login part is redirecting to another page, other  parts of the page remain unchanged.

Please help me to redirect my whole page when the user login is correct.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please help us to help you. How do you organize the parts of your page? How do you do the redirect? And how do you send the ajax login request? Please add related code (the part needed to better describe is only needed) to your question as well.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect client to another page with JS you can use:

```
window.location = '**url_to_redirect**';
```